# Flutter: The argument type 'HomePage Function(BuildContext, Map<String, dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and don't know the cause of the error.
I am using fluro for router.

However, I get the error shown in the image.

I would like to know the cause of this.

`fluro: ^2.0.3`

[image]

home.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('First Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: const Text('Next Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

router.dart

```dart
import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tel_app/pages/home.dart';

class Router {
  final router = FluroRouter();

  static Handler _homeHandler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>
          HomePage());

  void setupRouter() {
    router.define(
      '/',
      handler: _homeHandler,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are setting as home the widget you are in (`HomePage`), this must be a different widget.

Comment: I see.
I've edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seem that you need to allow the `BuildContext` to be `null` by using `BuildContext?` :

```
static Handler _homeHandler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>
          HomePage());
```

Source : https://github.com/lukepighetti/fluro/issues/240